# Change body html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the html of the body tag with jquery.

I have this body tag `<body>` When I click on a button, the body must change to
`<body ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);>`

How can I make that with `jquery` and `javascript`?

Comment: Do you really want to change the HTML or do you want to bind an event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
     $('body').attr('ontouchmove', "BlockMove(event)")
})
```

Or even better, don't change the DOM structure, just bind the the callback to the event:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
     $('body').bind('touchmove', BlockMove);
});
```

Comment: +1 Was just typing up the event handler version, you beat me to it :)

Comment: You don't want the "on" in the argument to `bind`: `.bind('touchmove' BockMove(event));`

Comment: @gdoron You beat me by few seconds :)

Comment: @gdoron - +1. Simple mistake to make! May also be worth noting that since jQuery attempts to normalize the event object you won't have access to touch-specific event properties. You will need to use `event.originalEvent` to get hold of the native event object.

Comment: @Alnitak. because of the `event`? I removed it.

Comment: @gdoron yes, because you were calling `BlockMove` immediately, not passing a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to change the real attribute - just add the function reference *directly* onto the body tag:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    document.body.ontouchmove = BlockMove;
});
```

or the jQuery way:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('body').on('touchmove', BlockMove);
});
```

Note that in the latter case you'll need to use `ev.originalEvent` to access the original event object, rather than jQuery's normalised event, which doesn't know about touch properties.

In the jQuery version you'll also need to ensure that this doesn't happen more than once, otherwise `BlockMove` will get *added* to the event handling chain over and over for each button press.  In the DOM0 version it doesn't matter because this one *overwrites* the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bind the event to body on click of button as:

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $("body").bind('touchmove', BlockMove);
});
```

Comment: [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411831/change-body-html-with-jquery/10411877#comment13432428_10411877) is true here as well

Comment: **The first comment is still true...** `$("body").bind('ontouchmove', BlockMove);` => `$("body").bind('touchmove', BlockMove);`

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested code):

```
$(body).attr("ontouchmove","blockMove(event)");
```